# How to setup Django logging to log to console and Debug Toolbar same time?

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

I try to setup logging in Django to use console and Django Debug Toolbar.
By default this line

```
logger.debug('XXXXX')
```

log to DDT, but console stay empty.

With this setup

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
}
```

logs appear in console, but disappear from DDT

How to make it works in both destinations?